# Copy padding style of an element

Tags: jquery, css, padding

I'm creating a jQuery plugin I need to create an element with exact padding of another element. will this be enough:

```
$(this).css('padding', otherElement.css('padding'));
```

or should I check for all:

```
$(this).css({
    'padding', otherElement.css('padding'),
    'padding-left', otherElement.css('padding-left'),
    'padding-right', otherElement.css('padding-right'),
    'padding-top', otherElement.css('padding-top'),
    'padding-bottom', otherElement.css('padding-bottom'),
});
```

Comment: This is literally a 2 minute job in a JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/AVZDC/

Comment: Why don't try for yourself?

Comment: If otherElement is having style padding and not separate paddings i.e left ,rigth etc then first can be used.

Comment: well these things might vary on jquery versions, browser and... so I want to use the experience of a person who has gone all the way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work.

Try:

```
$("#div2").click(function () {
    $(this).css("padding", $("#div1").css("padding"));
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SuBgR/1)

Comment: well I mean if the padding is not defined and only padding-left is defined , will `$(this).css("padding", $("#div1").css("padding"));` work?

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani. Answer = yes...http://jsfiddle.net/AVZDC/1/

Comment: This actually does not work. jQuery does not expose the shorthand padding property in this case.